# bash standard input redirection doesn't support wildcards?

Tags: bash, redirect

I have some files to process by redirecting them to standard input, but bash complains about the wildcards.

```
someprogram < data/*
```

The bash error is `bash: data/*: ambiguous redirect`, Is there any work arounds to accomplish this instead of using `cat` to read the files and pipe the contents to the program.

Comment: what is your expected behavior when `someprogram < data/*` is executed ? do you wan't the same result of `cat data/* | someprogram` ? if so, what wrong with it ?

Comment: by the way `zsh` has multios, though I never used this option:  http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#index-multios

Comment: @ymonad maybe the program will run faster

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible without using `cat`. Bash will open only a single file as stdin for a command. Btw, the is a *useful use of cat* :)

```
cat * | cmd
```

is the way to go here.

Comment: Not merely a useful use of cat, but the defining purpose of cat.